# exception tracking and blocking it in zend framework 2

Tags: exception, zend-framework2

How to stop exception  from showing in zend framework 2  and instead when exception is thrown i want to redirect to 404 page . 
Actually when user fires wrong url or some how any query gets executed in a wrong way  exception is thrown , so i need to block this exception and instead redirect to any other well designed page . I'm unable to track the the exception point or rather catch the exception or from where exception is generated . I have used this code 
        You can handle the exceptions in anyway you want after catching it as the following example in which you are catching the exception globally...:

In the onBootstrap method i have attached the following code in  Module.php in a function to execute when an event occurs, the following attach a function to be executed when an error (exception) is raised:

```
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
      $application = $e->getApplication();
        $em = $application->getEventManager();
        //handle the dispatch error (exception) 
       $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this,   
    'handleError'));
        //handle the view render error (exception) 
        $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, array($this, 
    'handleError'));
    }

and then defineed in module.php only  the function to handle the error

    public function handleError(MvcEvent $e)
    {
       //get the exception
       $exception = $e->getParam('exception');
       //...handle the exception... maybe log it and redirect to another page, 
        //or send an email that an exception occurred...
    }
```

I found this code from stackoverflow only , but it is not working , i mean when i'm passing wrong parameters in  url , it is showing  " A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.

Controller:
    Front\Controller\Front

No Exception available "

Please i need help on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can turn off exceptions in zf2 by chaining 'display_exceptions' => TRUE to 'display_exceptions' => false, [module/Application/config/module.config.php]

Comment: No i don't want to stop display of exception , but rather track the exception and show it or redirect to  one of my defined view.